# Using BeautifulSoup to extract date a post was created

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, code-formatting

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup 4 to scrape data from a recruitment website. Specifically, I want to extract the date when a job ad was posted. The HTML that involves this information is here:

```
<div class="posted-by">
Posted Today by 
<a href="/jobs/nhs-business-services-authority-72549/p72549" class="gtmJobListingPostedBy">NHS Business Services Authority</a> 
<span class=" "> <span data-qa="newMobileLbl" class="label label-new"  > New</span> </span>
</div>
```

I want to get "Today" from this code. To do this, I wrote the following code:

```
for job in jobs:
    postdate=job.find("div", attrs={"class":"posted-by"})
    print(postdate.text)
```

But this code returns

```
Posted Today by 
NHS Business Services Authority 
  New
```

instead of just "Today."

How can I correct my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [.next_element](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) . The .next_element attribute of a string or tag points to whatever was parsed immediately afterwards.

```
print(soup_obj.find('div',{'class': 'posted-by'}).next_element)
```

Comment: Please Upvote,accept this/any Answer which is useful to you